# php registration file error... can't find it.

Tags: php

Been lookin at this all night and I give up... 
The code is going straight from $result to the last line, so something is failing

Nothing is on the error log
Doesn't display an error message when it dies.
Just goes straight to reg_fail.html

```
<?php

$host = '.......'; // Host Name
$sql_username = '......'; // Sql Username
$sql_password = '.......'; // Password
$db_name = '..............'; //Database Name


$con = mysql_connect($host, $sql_username, $sql_password)or die('Error connecting to server');
mysql_select_db( $db_name)or die('Error connecting to database');


$firstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regFirstName']);
$lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regLastName']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regUser']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regEmail']);

$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regPassword']);
$password = md5($password);

$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());


if($result){

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count == 0){

    try{        



    $query = "INSERT INTO user (username, password, first_name, last_name, email)
                                 VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$email')";


    mysql_query($query , $con); 

    header('location: registration_success.html');  

    }catch(Exception $e){
    header('location: registration_fail_userTaken.html');
    }

}

header('location: registration_fail_userTaken.html');

}

header('location: registration_fail.html'); 




?>
```

Comment: Always have practice to add `exit;` after header redirect. And alos add `die(mysql_error());` after  mysql_query.

Comment: what is the actual error you get?

Comment: use `echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);` and `exit;` for tracing purpose. Exact after `$result = mysql_.....`

Comment: [Warning](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), [warning](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), [waaarning!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), [warning??](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php). In other words: [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Now what is output you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always send the last header, so even if you redirect to something, the last header will always redirect to "fail".

So just wrap it into `else`.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[exit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)** after each [header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). Or use `if(){}else{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
mysql_select_db( $db_name)or die('Error connecting to database');
```

to

```
mysql_select_db( $db_name ,$con)or die('Error connecting to database');
```